# unable to install docker in my conda environment

Tags: docker, installation, conda

I have been trying to install docker in a conda environment on a slurm server

I first tried

```
conda install -c conda-forge docker
```

but I got

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

- docker

Then I tried

```
pip install docker
```

which seems to install it successfully but when i try to run docker I get

```
command not found
```

in another post someone who had a similar problem resolved it with

```
sudo pip install docker
```

but this is not an option for me cause this is a server and I do not have administrative privileges

I am using miniconda and my conda version is 4.9.2

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: no it doesnt :( I guess there is no way around it, will have to contact the admin - thanks anyway, i just wanted to know if there is a quick fix

Answer (score 7):

Docker cannot be installed with Conda or from PyPI - only Python APIs are available (`docker-py` on Conda Forge; `docker` on PyPI). Docker itself requires elevated privileges to install.

FWIW, none of the HPC systems I've worked on allow Docker, but do provide Singularity instead.

Comment: hmm ok that's a good heads-up for the HPC users...